# the strange runtime of subprocess.py

Tags: python, time, subprocess

I run a program two days ago and take down the running time. By that time, the running time is about **160ms**, which is acceptable. However, today I run the same code on the same computer, only to find the time has risen up to **1600ms**, which is ten times of the formal one. How can a single program act so differently?

- I try to execute a `file` which has the `.py` estension with the subprocess module:

```
                    timestamp_start = time.time() * 1000
            
                    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                               close_fds=True)
                    try:
                        process.communicate(inputs.encode(encoding='UTF-8'), 10)
                        timestamp_end = time.time() * 1000
                    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                        print('用例运行超时！')
                        process.kill()
                        cls.afterTheEvaluate()
                        return True, 1, 'TIMEOUT', cls.lines
                    if process.returncode != 0:
                        print('代码运行错误')
                        process.kill()
                        cls.afterTheEvaluate()
                        return True, 1, 'ERROR', cls.lines

                    runtime += timestamp_end - timestamp_start
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any code that is actually relevant to the problem.  This mysterious second program might be running slower because you're giving it more work to do, or because some resource it depends on (such as a network connection) is responding slower than usual today.  How could we even guess, without any information about the other program at all?

Comment: But there isn't other code relevant at all. The time is to show how long it takes to run the subprocess.communicate(). If I know what cause the problem, (maybe the cpu traffic or os problem), why should I ask?

Comment: And the .py file called by subprocess has only one line of code: "print(2, end=' '')", no more. The time is mainly cost by subprocess, and it changes dramaticly.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your comment, the problem is quite strange that I don't know how to make you understand. Sorry.

Comment: Can you [edit] your code to turn the example code into a [mcve] that demonstrates the slowdown? There's a lot of undefined stuff in your current example that might be varying between the runs you describe.